# Database unit test

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am hoping to get some advice on a unit test I am writing for to test some db entries.

The function I am testing seeds the database if no records are found.

```
func Seed(db *gorm.DB) {
    var data []Data
    db.Find(&data)

    if len(data) == 0 {
      // do seed default data
    }

}
```

What I can't quite seem to get going is the test for that if len test. I am using a test db so I can nuke it whenever so it is not an issue if I just need to force an empty DB on the function.

The function itself works and I just want to make sure I get that covered.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: where is `users` define?

Comment: Don't use a database for your tests. Use a mock. [go-sqlmock](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock) is the one I use. Anything else isn't actually a unit test.

Comment: Thanks Flimzy I will take a look at sqlmock. Appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends, there are so many ways of addressing this based on your risk level and the amount of time you want to invest to mitigate those risks.

- You could write a unit test that asserts your able to detect and act on users logic (ie seeding when empty and ignoring when full) without any database.
- If you would like to test the logic as well as your programs ability to speak to mysql correctly through the `gorm` library you could:

  - Have a test where you call `Seed` with no users in the DB, after calling it your test could select from `Users` and make sure there are the expected entries created from `len(users) == 0` conditional
  - Have a test where the test creates a single entry and calls `Seed`, after which asserting that underlying tables are empty.

---

It can get more complicated.  If `Seed` is selecting a subset of data than your test could insert 2 users, one that qualifies and one that doesnt', and make sure that no new users are `Seed`ed.

Comment: I will give that a try tomorrow. Sounds like a good way to go. As the dB is just spun up in a container whenever the tests are run so the data is unimportant. Thanks! I’ll let you know how it goes.