# Unit testing strategy for database connection get

Tags: unit-testing, go

There's a method in the code under test, that simply tries to get database connection, or returns error if unable to.

It, and the structs involved are defined as follows:

```
type DatabaseContext struct {
    Context
    Database DatabaseSt
}


// //GetInfo Returns the context.
// func (c *DatabaseContext) GetInfo() *Context {
//  return &c.Context
// }

//GetDB Gets the database connection from the connection string.
func (c *DatabaseContext) GetDB() (*sql.DB, *errors.ErrorSt) {
    var errSt *errors.ErrorSt
    if c.Database.dbConnection == nil {
        c.Database.dbConnection, errSt = c.openDB()
        if errSt != nil {
            return nil, errSt
        }
        c.Database.dbConnection.SetMaxOpenConns(50)
    }
    return c.Database.dbConnection, nil
}
```

The other methods, in the same file, which it may hit, are as follows:

```
//openDB opens the database with the connection string.
func (c *DatabaseContext) openDB() (*sql.DB, *errors.ErrorSt) {
    if c.Database.DBConnectionStr == "" {
        c.GetDatabase()
    }
    return db.OpenConnection(c.Database.DBConnectionStr, c.Database.InterpolateParams)

}

//CloseDB Closes the database.
func (c *DatabaseContext) CloseDB() {
    if c.Database.dbConnection != nil {
        c.Database.dbConnection.Close()
    }
}

//SetDatabaseString Sets the database string into the session.
func (c *DatabaseContext) SetDatabaseString(str string) {
    c.Database.DBConnectionStr = str
    i := strings.Index(str, ")/") + 2
    c.Database.DBName = str[i:]
    c.SetDatabase()
}

//GetDatabaseString Gets the database string from the session.
func (c *DatabaseContext) GetDatabase() {
    if dbIntf := c.GetFromSession("Database"); dbIntf != nil {
        c.Database = dbIntf.(DatabaseSt)
    }
}

//SetDatabaseString Sets the database string into the session.
func (c *DatabaseContext) SetDatabase() {
    c.SetToSession("Database", c.Database)
}
```

Fortunately, `DatabaseContext` implements `DatabaseContextIntf`, which I want to use for testing. My instinct is to straight up mock `DatabaseContext`, but that won't work because it's not an interface (in Golang, you can only mock interfaces).

How would I go about testing this, without hitting a real database, which can fail beyond my control (thus creating false fails in the test)?

**UPDATE** My question differs from the suspected duplicate as their question is about database **entries**, and not connections. The flagged duplicate refers to [this library](https://godoc.org/github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock) as the answer, however, there is no method in it to return a "connection" that is nil, for the sake of the test. The best it has is [`New`](https://godoc.org/github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock#New) which creates a test double connection, and there's no way to control the state of the returned value (I need it to be `nil` in one test ("No Connection") and non-nil in another ("Sanity Test"))

Comment: You know you can only mock interfaces, and you have an interface type already, is there some reason you aren't mocking that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang Database unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272973/golang-database-unit-test)

Comment: I just tried, but it gets me no test coverage. I tried it with defining what `GetDB()` should return for the test

Comment: Mine is not a duplicate of that, @Flimzy , as that one is about database **entries**, whereas mine is about the business method to get the connection itself.

Comment: @MikeWarren: The answer is the same in both cases, so yes, it is a duplicate.

Comment: In short, the answer is: "there are many ways to do this. You need a mock of some sort."

Comment: I just said "I just tried, but it gets me no test coverage. I tried it with defining what `GetDB()` should return for the test, and it got no test coverage. 

I just came up with something upon further inspection of the code under test (it depends on more functions inside that same file, and ultimately one outside, which hits a third party method that I'm about to stub.

Comment: Even worse, when I use `mockery` to generate the mocks, it puts them in package `mocks` and then refers back to the package the test and the code are in, causing circular dependency issues because of Golang's compiler weakness.

Comment: You actually can tell mockery where to put the mocks...

Comment: Do you want to test GetDB, or do you want to test something that uses GetDB?

Comment: I want to test `GetDB`.

Comment: In that case creating a mock for `DatabaseContextIntf` makes no sense, so your "Fortunately" might throw people of, as there is no fortune in that...

Comment: And you seem to be connecting to the db through a single point namely `db.OpenConnection`, which appears to be either a global variable `db` or a globally accessible function `OpenConnection`... In my opinion globals are not good candidates for test doubles but whatever, you could mock a func like `OpenConnection` if it is a func variable, e.g. `var OpenConnection = func(...`, then during testing you would just reassign the variable to a mock func for example.

Comment: ... if, however, `OpenConnection` is a normal func and not a variable, then you can't mock it, you'll have to introduce an extra level of indirection if you want to test your GetDB without hitting the db.

Comment: hope that makes sense, let me know if not and i'll provide an example.

Comment: It is a function in our `db` package, in which I just discovered an unreachable line of code

Comment: @MikeWarren here's what i meant by the extra indirection in my previous comment: https://play.golang.org/p/E4Y9Hiwmk_-

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making the package of the test the same as that of the code under test (this allows the test generator in Visual Studio Code to place the generated test right in the test file, and not get confused, as well as give me access to unexported fields, which I used), and just straight up made a fake `DatabaseContext`

My test case looks like this:

```
t.Run("SanityTest", func(t *testing.T) {
    c := new(DatabaseContext)
    assert.Nil(t, c.Database.dbConnection)
    database, err := c.GetDB()
    defer database.Close()
    assert.NotNil(t, database)
    if !assert.Nil(t, err) {
        t.Error(err.ToString(false))
    }
})
```